# How to access other tables with Python Script in PowerBI?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi

let's say I am currently using a Python Script on Table 2 and I want to access a column from Table 1. Table 1 and Table 2 have a relation. How can I access that specific column of Table 1 ? It says 'dataset' has stored all the data of Table 2 but I could not find out how to also work with related tables within the Python Script.

Example of what I want: `dataset[Column3] = dataset["Column2] * Table1["Column5"]`

I thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use the [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function.

Comment: So there is no way around it, I see. How would I adress the Table 2 within the merge method in PowerBI? Would it be something like 
´dataset.merge("Table 2", left_on='column1', right_on='column2')´

Comment: Hi, not sure what do you mean by `there is no way around it`. The rest of your comment is pretty much what you need. You have to somehow relate both tables to one another. In pandas this is done by `merge()`. In PowerBI this is similar, where you just join tables (or using functions like `VLOOKUP` in Excel).

Comment: The tables are related I just need to know how to name the Table2 within the merge method within PowerBI.
Can I just say dataset.merge("Table 2",.....)  ?